# Rcpp port of a linear algebra function in R

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp, rcpparmadillo, nmf

The following is an objective function for symmetrical non-negative matrix factorization that I'm trying to port into Rcpp:

```
fit_H <- function(W,H, num.iter){
  for(i in 1:num.iter){
    H <- 0.5*(H*(1+(crossprod(W,H)/tcrossprod(H,crossprod(H)))))
  }
  H
}

H <- fit_H(W,H, num.iter = 100)
```

Here's my stab (with plenty of things wrong, to be sure) at an Rcpp translation:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP eigenMatMult(Eigen::MatrixXd W, Eigen::MatrixXd H){
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = 0.5 * H * (1 + ((W*H)/(trans(H)*(H*H))));

    return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}
```

What's the correct (and fastest) single-core translation?

**Theoretical background:** Iteration of this function drives convergence to an `H` such that `HH^T` approximately equals `W`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347453/symmetric-non-negative-matrix-factorization-in-r/64625311#64625311) (and my answer there) for background.

Comment: why the for-loop? It seems to have no purpose in your first example.

Comment: @Oliver I'd like to repeat the function `num.iter` times. With each iteration, H is being updated for use in the next iteration.  I don't want to be doing the for-loop in R and passing H through Rcpp with each iteration.

Comment: @Oliver Ah, code corrected!  I previously indicated variable `D` as what should have been `H`. One of those Stack-O copy-paste simplification jobs gone wrong :(

Comment: Now that you've edited your question, If the actual problem is like the one shown, I'd simply stay in R. Matrix operations are performed in optimized C code, so I wouldn't expect to see any grand (if any at all) improvements. One thing to note however, is to set `rng = false` in `Rcpp`, as the exporting of seed takes a not insignificant amount of time (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288999/10782538)). It seems that you are mostly missing a for-loop and transposing some objects (which are transposed by `crossprod`).

Comment: @Oliver thanks again! I’d mark that comment as the accepted answer if I could. I read your answer in the question you linked and it clearly shows Rcpp is not always faster than Optimized R functions. I’ll look into ways to optimize the objective function in R.